# Multiple H3 tags using different text & font style

Tags: html, css, tags

How can I make multiple H3 tags using different text style & font size inside post body?

My H3 CSS is look like this

```
.post h3{
         border-top:1px dotted #84ce31;
         border-bottom:1px dotted #84ce31;
         font-size: 10pt;padding:3px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there can be done by either adding the id or the class  like

```
.post h3.#hea1{ color: white; }
.post h3.#hea2{ color: black; }
.post h3.#hea3{ color: red; }
```

or as class explained above

not point is that what should be use ..to know that you must know

difference between id and class

**ID's are unique**

```
Each element can have only one ID
Each page can have only one element with that ID
```

**Classes are NOT unique**

```
You can use the same class on multiple elements.
You can use multiple classes on the same element.
```

**note : There are no browser defaults for any ID or Class**

Adding a class name or ID to an element does nothing to that element by default.

This is something that snagged me as a beginner. You are working on one site and figure out that applying a particular class name fixes a problem you are having. Then you jump over to another site with the same problem and try to fix it with that same class name thinking the class name itself has some magical property to it only to find out it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Give each one of them a class:

```
.post h3.class1 { color: white; }
.post h3.class2 { color: black; }
.post h3.class3 { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give them all ID's. ID's are meant for special Identification of elements that only exists once and use classes for more common recurring styles with just the h3 style at a default that will be appearing most often. All that said the answer is not wrong either, I am just considering design styles.